# How to serve static files inside EJS recursive view folder?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

```
Suppose i have the following directory.

 |--Views/
 |    --partial/
 |       --links.ejs
 |
 |--assets/
 |    --css/
 |      --styles.css
 |
 |--server.js
```

Code for **links.ejs**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/forms/switches.css">
```

**Code for SERVER.JS**

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path');

let app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use( express.static("/assets/"));
app.use(express.static("bootstrap/css/"))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.render(`auth_login_boxed`);
});

console.log(a);

app.listen(8000);
```

And i want to server static file "Assets" folder inside partial folder.
How to create a relative path in express to serve css file inside my links.ejs code ?
I don't know if these supports in express ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a folder at your directory level called `public`
2. Set your app.use statement to be `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));`
3. Reference your static directory by `<link href="/assets/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">` (using your CSS sheet for example)